# Are global complete intersections detectable from any presentation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and let $A$ be a finite type $k$-algebra that is a (global) complete intersection, i.e. there exists some presentation

$$ A = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$$

such that $I$ has a generating set of cardinality $n - \dim_{Krull} A$.

Let now $A = k[X_1,\dots,X_N]/J$ be an *arbitrary* presentation of $A$.

> (A) Can one conclude $J$ has a generating set of cardinality $N - \dim_{Krull} A$?

I assume the answer is *no* in general, see below. If this is true, does it become *yes* if $A$ is a graded ring?

> (B) If the answer to (A) is **no** in general but we assume that $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $k[X_1,\dots,X_N]$ are positively graded (although perhaps the $x_i$'s and $X_j$'s have varying degrees), and that $I$ and $J$ are graded ideals, then does the answer to (A) become *yes*?

I assume the answer to (A) is no in general because the Stacks Project, [Lemma 10.133.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00SC), asserts a result that is close to (A) but localized: given a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, then there exists $x\in A\setminus\mathfrak{p}$ such that $A_x$ is a global complete intersection if and only if $J_\mathfrak{P}$ in $k[X_1,\dots,X_N]_\mathfrak{P}$ can be generated by the right number of elements, where $\mathfrak{P}$ is the pullback of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $k[X_1,\dots,X_N]$. If $A$ is a global complete intersection, the first condition is met for every $\mathfrak{p}$, thus so is the second; but on the other hand this is also true if $A$ is a local, but not global, complete intersection (by which I mean there is a collection of $y_i$'s generating the unit ideal in $A$ such that each $A_{y_i}$ is a complete intersection). So a yes for (A) does not appear to follow from this lemma.

On the other hand, for a *local* $k$-algebra essentially of finite type, the analogous claim to (A) is true: see Stacks Project lemmas [10.133.6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00SE) and [10.133.7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00SF). And what is true in the local case is also often true in the graded-over-a-field case. Hence question (B).

Looking forward to your thoughts!

Comment: Have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636748/is-there-an-easy-criterion-to-determine-whether-given-polynomials-form-a-complet

Comment: If you assume that $A$ is smooth over $k$, then this is true if $N\geq 2\dim A+2$.

Comment: @Mohan - That's cool and makes me curious - do you know a reference?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - I hadn't, but, now that I have: the accepted answer at that link seems to presume the answer to (B) is *yes* but does not argue this, or am I missing something?

Comment: See my paper (N. Mohan Kumar, Kyoto Journal,1976 or 77). The results are reproved in Kunz's book as well as the Italian version of Atiyah and McDonald.

Comment: @Mohan - wow, thank you so much!

Comment: @Mohan The paper you are referring to is probably this: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250522714

Comment: @user26857 Yes, thanks.